How to count the number of topological sorts in a directed acyclic graph with multiple roots
I have a task to count the number of possible topological sorts, and it is known that the graph has N vertices and N-1 edges, and the edges are also given.
For example:
N = 4
1 2
1 3
4 3
For this graph, the answer will be 5 possible sorts, with nodes 1 and 4 being the roots.
I assume that to solve this correctly, one needs to traverse all roots using DFS. When searching for the number of sorts for a particular root, at each step, one should find the product of the topological sorts of its children multiplied by the polynomial coefficient of the node, where the node has n + 1 children, and the subgraphs t1,…,tr of the children have k1,…,kr nodes respectively (so n=k1+⋯+kr). Let NoS(t) be the number of topsorts of tree t. Then
$$ NoS(t) = \Biggl(\frac {n!} {k1!⋯kr!}\Biggr)∏NoS(ti) $$
After finding the number of topological sorts for each of the roots, I assume that they somehow combine to obtain the total number of sorts for the entire graph, but I do not know how to combine them exactly.
If this is correct I'd really appreciate some help with proving correctness and if not a explanation why and a clue could be nice :)

What is the question?

The question is how to count the number of possible topological sorts in a directed acyclic graph with multiple roots of in-degree 0. This is a general question regarding the problem. As mentioned above, I found a way to count the number of topological sorts for one of the roots, but I don't know how to account for the entire graph as a whole, since this formula NoS only considers the children of the root, not the entire graph

Your idea might make sense, at least it seems to me that i could try experimenting with it, but in the formulation in which you presented this idea, unfortunately, it is incorrect because there will be too many children

The problem is #P-complete (for example, see the last example in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%99%AFP-complete#Examples), so you should not expect any efficient algorithm that works on all directed acyclic graphs.
For an algorithm (without requiring it run in polynomial time), see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3220701/14578, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2933640/14578, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/814177/14578.

Thank you, your answer helped me a lot! How could I not see this part on the wiki?!
